# What is the shape of Decision Boundary for binary classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

There are different types of Binary Classifiers each will produce a different type of decision boundary some produce decision boundary as straight-line others as circle or square, some of the classifiers also produce decision boundaries as polynomial functions. Which are the Binary Classifiers which produce straight line as decision boundary? What are the other shapes of decision boundaries associated with each algorithm?